# cross reference doesn't work with memoir

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, cross-referencing, memoir

I'm getting to know `memoir`, and I cannot make cross references work.

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  hypertexnames=true,                
  linktocpage=true,
  linktoc=section,
  colorlinks=true,                                        
}
\usepackage{makeidx} % enables indexing
\makeindex
```

These are the major packages I'm loading and `cleveref` in addition. However, cross references in the document doesn't work. Neither in the TOC nor in when using `\cref` nor `\ref`. What am I missing? If I need to provide more information let me know.

Comment: Please expand your code into a standalone MWE (minimum working example) that shows how you're defining the items' labels and how you're using the cross-referencing commands. The reason I suggest this is because I've taken your code and expanded it into an MWE -- and I can't seem to replicate the problems you're describing. (Did you remember to run LaTeX *twice* so let it resolve the cross-references?)

Comment: Please post you solution as a self-answer then (or delete the question altogether if you think the issue was only minor after all).

Comment: @MartinScharrer: I don't know whether this is minor or not. I couldn't find this behavior documented; but maybe I didn't look in the right places... Maybe the best would be to close the question?

Comment: Just post your findings in an answer and accept it after the time limit allows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, apparently the problem is the class' option draft. Here's the very beginning of my document:

```
\documentclass[%
stockaiv,%
pageaiv,%
extrafontsizes,%
11pt,%
twoside,%
draft%
]{memoir}
\fixpdflayout
```

and once removing the draft option all cross references worked as expected (as far as I can tell now). I couldn't find any reference to this behavior in the class' documentation.

Comment: Since `memoir` does not provide hyperlinks, it might be an idea to check elsewhere. As far as I can see `hyperref` reacts to the draft option. All class options are also given to packages (which is quite handy)

Comment: @daleif: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: You mention, that you cannot understand why this is not in the manual. I mentioned that hyperlinks does not come from `memoir`, thus of course it is not a part of the manual. Many things behave strange when the draft option is added (e.g. the listings package)

Comment: @daleif: I meant documentation in the broader sense. Anyway, now this interaction (i.e. `memior` with its `draft` option and `hyperref` is sort of documented.